# Как задать маршрут по умолчанию при использовании [Route] & [ActionName] в методе контроллера?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть контроллер `Operation` для него установлен атрибут маршрутизации `[RoutePrefix]`, у него есть метод `GetOperationList` с установленным атрибутом маршрутизации `[Route]` и атрибутом `[ActionName]`

```
[RoutePrefix("Operation/{operationId}")]
public class OperationController: Controller
{
    [Route("~/Operations"), ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult GetOperationList(){}
}
```

ссылки генерируемые методом `Html.ActionLink` и `Url.Action` выглядят как `/Operations`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{не пойму как должна выглядеть строка адреса }"
);
```

Пробовал задать `url` как `/Operations` получаю `Exception`

> The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.
>   Parameter name: routeUrl

Подскажите как должная выглядеть строка `url` для маршрута по умолчанию на метод `Index` контроллера `Operation`

При попытке открыть сайт:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0

---

вроде бы помогло добавление дополнительного атрибута `[Route(/~)]` но я не уверен в правильности такого способа

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42825/discussion-on-question-by-bald-------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как бы это странно не было, но помогло добавление еще одного атрибута маршрутизации к методу `GetOperationList`:

```
[Route("~/")]
[Route("~/Operations")]        
[ActionName("Index")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult GetOperationList()
{
    var model = _operationService2.GetOperationList();
    return View("OperationList", model);
}
```

где то в `RouteConfig`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Operation", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```